# Raise Base Class Event VB.NET Entity Framework Partial Class

Tags: vb.net, entity-framework

I have a partial class to add some functionality to an Entitiy Framework class.
I want to RaiseEvent PropertyChanged when I change any properties that are only in the partial part of the class.

I'm getting:
Derived classes cannot raise base class events

```
Partial Class Person
    Sub NotifyPropertyChanged(ByVal name As String)
        RaiseEvent PropertyChanged(Me, New PropertyChangedEventArgs(name))
    End Sub
End Class
```

Any ideas on how to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem has nothing to do with partial classes.  The problem is that `Person` derives from another class, and you're trying to raise an event declared in the base class from within the `Person` class.

The solution is to create a protected method in the base class that raises the event, and call it from within the person class.

Comment: How would I go about doing that, is the base class not autogenerated from EF? Would this get overwritten everytime the database schema changed and I regenerated the file?

Comment: Yes, if you're using the model-first approach where the entities are auto-generated, you're going to have a hard time adding any functionality to the base class.  Instead of adding non-persisted properties to the entity via a partial class, I'd recommend wrapping it inside a different object.  It's hard to say what the best solution would be without knowing more about the problem you're trying to solve.

Comment: I'm not using model-first, I'm generating model from an existing db.

Comment: Ahh, well, either way it's being auto-generated.